# sending ImageMagick object in openMPI, C++

Tags: c++, imagemagick, mpi, openmpi

I have a severe problem in my project. I need to send an image data to another node in the cluster. I read the images with ImageMagick, as like:

```
Image testImage;

// read in the file
testImage.read("image.png");
```

And i send it as:

```
MPI_Send( &testImage, sizeof(Image), MPI_BYTE, i , 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

the other nodes should receive it as:

```
Image subimage_toModify;
MPI_Recv( &subimage_toModify, sizeof(Image), MPI_BYTE, 0, 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

But i get a Segmentation Fault:

```
Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
```

can anyone be of any help? i am almost frustrated !

Comment: @Nikola, I did not understand your answer!

Comment: try to use just subimage_toModify no again the address.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer, but this generates an error:`error: cannot convert ‘Magick::Image’ to ‘void*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int MPI_Recv(void*, int, ompi_datatype_t*, int, int, ompi_communicator_t*, MPI_Status*)’`

Answer (score 3):

The `Image` class is not a POD type, therefore you can not send it using `MPI_Send`

The simplest way to do it is to send BLOB data, which you can get from the Image object, but it might not be optimal. So, do it like this :

```
Image testImage;

// read in the file
testImage.read("image.png");

Blob blob;
testImage.write( & blob );
int size = blob.length();
MPI_Send( &size, sizeof( size ), MPI_BYTE, i , 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send( blob.data(), blob.length(), MPI_BYTE, i , 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

To receive :

```
int size = 0;
MPI_Recv( &size, sizeof( size ), MPI_BYTE, 0, 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
std::vector< unsigned char > tempBuffer( size, 0 );
MPI_Recv( &tempBuffer[0], tempBuffer.size(), MPI_BYTE, 0, 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
Blob blob( &tempBuffer[0], tempBuffer.size());
```

Comment: any ideas how I can send it then? like transforming it into an array and rebuilding the image upon receiving?

Comment: thanks for the answer. However this method run into errors like: `error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘void*’
aks.c++:115:89: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int MPI_Send(void*, int, ompi_datatype_t*, int, int, ompi_communicator_t*)’ `  . I appreciate if you can elaborate on the receiving end, too. Thank you very much. 
`

Comment: i solved this by adding a const_cast<void*> to your code. Would you please help me about the receiving end? thanks!

Comment: @camelian77 modified example. now it includes sending and receiving